# How to assign address of array to pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int arr[2] = {1, 2};
  int *p;
  // p = &arr; // Does not compile
  p = &arr[0]; // compiles
  std::cout << "&arr    = " << &arr << std::endl;
  std::cout << "&arr[0] = " << &arr[0] << std::endl;
}
```

When I try to print the address both print the same address. But when I try to assign `p = &arr` it does not compile. Is there something in standard that says something against assigning address of array to pointer. I just wanted to know the reason why  `p = &arr` does not compile?

Clang actually says `error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type`

Comment: `p = &arr[0]` compiles because `&arr[0]` is the address of the first element of the array.  I suspect that `p = &arr` doesn't compile because `arr` is *already a memory address.*  Try `p==arr;`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `arr` is an array, not an address

Comment: @M.M It's an address, the address of the first element in the array.  Arrays degrade to pointers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey they can be converted to pointers in the appropriate context... but an array isn't a pointer any more than `5` is a `double` because you could go `void f(double);  f(5);`.   `&arr` is not such a context either.

Comment: M.M is right, see the end of my post I use typeid to show it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p = &arr;`

is a compiler error because the type of `&arr` is `int (*)[2]` -- pointer to an "array of 2 `int`s". Hence, it cannot be assigned to `p`, whose type is `int*`.

Even though `&arr` and `&arr[0]` evaluate to the same numerical value, they are different types.

Comment: @pokche, in that context, `arr` is the same as `&arr[0]`.

Comment: do you know the why arr is same as &arr[0] ?

Comment: @pokche, the standard defines it that way. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.array.

Comment: In C and C++, an array variable is essentially a pointer to the first item in the array.  Do a Google search for "array decay."

Comment: name of the array denotes the base address of array. in statement p=arr you are storing address of array arr into pointer p which is valid.

Comment: Robert Harvey is right, I tested: pointer = &arr[0] is same pointer = arr. When we use a variable, we have to use the "&" before that variable, it's not required for an array.

Answer (score 0):

So you have this:

```
arr[0] is the first item in memory
arr[1] is the second item in memory
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
*((int*)arr + 0) is the first item in memory
*((int*)arr + 1) is the second item in memory
```

"Dereference" the pointer, this lets you access the memory you want instead of the number which represents it in memory (the pointer):

```
*((int*)arr + 0)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
arr[0]
```

If you wanted the address of any item you can do as shown here:

```
(int*)arr + Index
```

The address of the first item is the memory address of the start of the array, so the address of the array AND the first item is:

```
(int*)arr + 0 or just (int*)arr
```

Your code here gets the address of the first item, which is the same as the address of the array:

```
p = &arr[0]; // compiles
```

Whenever you place an ampersand ( & ) its equivalent to getting the address of, so here you are getting [**the address of the address of the array**], this is not the same as the [**address of the array**]

```
p = &arr; // Does not compile
```

The type of the address of the address of the array is:

```
int (*)[2];
```

Not:

```
int *p;
```

That is why it doesn't compile, the types don't match.

To help with type related errors like this one you can use typeid and decltype, in C++ this lets you print the name of the type in question.

Like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[2] = {1, 2};

    std::cout<< "typeid ptr_array is " << typeid(decltype(&arr)).name() << "\n";
    std::cout<< "typeid ptr_item is " << typeid(decltype(&arr[0])).name() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
ptr_array is PA2_i (Pointer to Array of size 2 with int)
ptr_item is Pi     (Pointer to int)
```

"P" from typeid means pointer, "A" means array.

You can play around yourself here:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/RNNxjTMSUnLqUo6q

Comment: So r u saying int **p = &arr; ?

Comment: This is wrong; the type of the array's address is `int (*)[2]`, not `int **`

Comment: I understand the casts should be static_cast, but its more verbose in this example. To change or not to change.

Comment: pokche, no sorry that was a mistake. 
The type is as shown from typeid, the type of an array is an array. The pointer to  that type is simply a pointer to that type or int (*)[2].